# Solution of Lagrange PDE: $(z^2-2yz-y^2)p+(xy+zx)q= xy-zx$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This question has already been asked. But in that question, user was having difficulty in finding the second integral. My question is different. It says that if the solution to the above PDE represents a sphere, what will be the coordinates of that sphere? I am taking the solution as
$ x^2+y^2+z^2= f(z^2+2yz-y^2)$.

Could I say that the centre will be $(0,0,0)$? Or there is more to it than that meets the eyes? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(z^2-2yz-y^2)z_x+(xy+zx)z_y= xy-zx$$
Charpit-Lagrange :
$$\frac{dx}{z^2-2yz-y^2}=\frac{dy}{xy+zx}=\frac{dz}{xy-zx}$$
First characteristic equation from solving $\frac{dy}{xy+zx}=\frac{dz}{xy-zx}\quad;\quad \frac{dz}{dy}=\frac{y-z}{y+z}$ :
$$z^2+2yz-y^2=c_1$$
Second characteristic equation from

$\frac{dx}{z^2-2yz-y^2}=\frac{dy}{xy+zx}=\frac{dz}{xy-zx}=\frac{xdx+ydy+zdz}{x(z^2-2yz-y^2)+y(xy+zx)+z(xy-zx)}=\frac{xdx+ydy+zdz}{0}\implies xdx+ydy+zdz=0$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $c_2=f(c_1)$ with arbitrary function $f$ :
$$\boxed{x^2+y^2+z^2=f(z^2+2yz-y^2)}$$
In the particular case $f=$constant$=R^2$ the solutions are spheres of any radius and center $(0,0,0)$.

The question is : Is there other(s) sphere(s) which are solution of the PDE ? This would imply that a non-constant function $f$ exists such as $f(z^2+2yz-y^2)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ be equivalent to $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=R^2$.  This is not possible since $f(z^2+2yz-y^2)$ is function of $(yz)$ while $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2$ is not function of $(yz)$.

A more direct proof consists in putting $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=R^2$ into the original PDE with $z_x=-\frac{x-a}{z-c}$ and $z_y=-\frac{y-b}{z-c}$. After a booring task of simplification the unique result is $a=b=c=0$.